# UI Bootstrap Modal open programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I can open my UI Bootstrap Modal with a button but how do I open it within my Ctrl programmatically?

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/Cdq2d9l1XxCi10bFXtBt?p=preview

js:

```
  // open modal if this is true
  $scope.openModal = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
```

html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: `$scope.open(<size>);`

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to call in your Controller.

> $scope.open();

Where Ever you want the modal to show in your Controller.

Comment: If you want running snippet I can post. And if it works please like my Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
angular.element('#myModalContent.html').trigger('click');
```

That should cause the controller to act like the button was clicked on when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just triggering `$scope.open(size)` on a click, you can simply call that function wherever and whenever you want, as Saurabh already mentioned.

Alternatively, if you want to trigger a 'real click event' on that button, you may use `angular.element`. A working example for your code could look somehow like this:

```
angular.element('#your_button_id').triggerHandler('click');
```

This will simply imitate a click, as if you would have clicked with your mouse, which will then trigger your function and open the modal.